# GKE: use existing disk in multiple zones

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, disk

I would like to mount existing GCP disk to pods in a GKE regional cluster.

Following [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd) guide I have:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 100G
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  claimRef:
    name: pvc
    namespace: default
  csi:
    driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: "projects/<proj>/regions/<region>/disks/<disk_name>"
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  volumeName: pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100G

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sd
          image: alpine
          volumeMounts:
            - name: app
              mountPath: /app
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: app
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc
            readOnly: true
```

Let's assume that the disk is regional and available in zone A and B.

It will work as expected if the node will be created in the zone A or B, but if it is created in zone C it fails as the disk cannot be mounted.

Is there a way to let GKE replicate the disk in multiple zones and mount the appropriate disk/zone based on the replica location?
Or is there a way to point the PV to multiple disks (1 per zone) and let GKE pick the right one based on the replica's zone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, in "cloud native" software, disks are typically only available in a single Availability Zone. In "cloud native" software, it is the softwares responsibility to replicate data to multiple zones, this is software deployed as *stateful* software. That said, GCP do offer regional disks.

### Regional disks in GCP

You **can** use regional persistent disks on GCP. To do that, you have to create a specific `StorageClass` and specify that `storageClassName` in your `PersistentVolumeClaim`. See [Provisioning regional persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/regional-pd) on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
As I said in my open post, even if I create a regional disk it is limited to 2 zones.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PersistentVolume` per zone and let `PersistentVolumeClaim` select the correct one based on the pod zone:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-a
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 50G
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  csi:
    driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: "projects/<project>/zones/<zone_a>/disks/<disk_a>"
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            operator: In
            values:
              - <zone_a>

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-b
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 50G
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  csi:
    driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: "projects/<project>/zones/<zone_b>/disks/<disk_b>"
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            operator: In
            values:
              - <zone_b>

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50G

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: docker.io/alpine
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
          args:
            - sleep 9999
          volumeMounts:
            - name: disk
              mountPath: /disk
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: disk
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc
            readOnly: true
```